# 4-dimensional array allocation: access violation

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, matrix, allocation

I wrote this simple piece of code to dynamically allocate a 4-dimensional array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int**** alloc() {

    int i,j,k;
    int ****matrix;
    int x,y,z,n_pairs;

    x= 62;
    y= 45;
    z= 28;
    n_pairs = 4;

    matrix = (int ****) malloc(x*sizeof(int***));

    for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int ***) malloc(y*sizeof(int**));

        if(matrix[i]==NULL)
            return NULL;

        for (j=0; j<y; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (int **) malloc(z*sizeof(int*));

            if (matrix[i][j] == NULL)
                return NULL;

            for (k=0; k<n_pairs; k++) {
                matrix[i][j][k] = (int *)calloc(n_pairs,sizeof(int));

                if (matrix[i][j][k] == NULL)
                    return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}


void freeMatrix(int ****m) {

    int i,j,k;
    int x,y,z;

    x= 62;
    y= 45;
    z= 28;


    for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<y; j++) {
            for(k=0; k<z; k++) 
                free(m[i][j][k]);

            free(m[i][j]);
        }

        free(m[i]);
    }

    free(m);
}

int main() {

    int i,j,k,h;
    int ****m = NULL;

    m = alloc();

    for(i=0;i<62;i++)
        for(j=0;j<45;j++)
            for(k=0;k<28;k++)
                for(h=0;h<4;h++)
                    printf("%d\t",m[i][j][k][h]);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

the problem is that I this code results in an `Access Violation` when I try to execute it. 
Isn't it the correct way to allocate/free a multidimensional array? If yes, then what is the problem?

Comment: Please don't call this a 4D array, this is only an emulation of such a beast. C has N-dimensinal arrays natively. They are very easy to use and you avoid part of the difficulties that you encounter here. `int (A*)[4][5][23] = calloc(37 * sizeof *A);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
        for (k=0; k<n_pairs; k++) { //<----- This should read `k<z'
            matrix[i][j][k] = (int *)calloc(n_pairs,sizeof(int));
```

You probably meant to loop to `z`, not to `n_pairs`.

Comment: such a stupid error...I'm sorry! I will accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: @aix you should probably give a go at sniping as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

if u make a matrix the correct way is to allocate all the memory u need, then dived it up.

for 2.dim

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  int ** matrix;
  int rows = 10;
  int colums =10;


  matrix = (int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
  matrix[0] = (int*)malloc(rows*colums*sizeof(int));

  for(i =1; i<rows;i++)
    matrix[i] = &matrix[i-1][colums];

  free(matrix[0]);
  free(matrix);
  return 0;
}
```

this is for having a continues memory area for the matrix. this can be faster